# Guidence with Laplace Transforation

Tags: laplace-transform

I am stumped on this problem. I think my procedure is incorrect. If someone could take a look at guide me through, I would be most appreciative.

The problem states: Use to definition of Laplace Transform to find $L{f(t)}$.

We know the defintion of the Laplace Transform is:

$F(s) = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt$

so $f(t) = e^{t+7}$ and I began to simplify the integrand to find:

$e^{-st+t+7}$ if I let $u=-st + t+ 7$ then $du=(-s+1)dt$ Integrating that is

$\int_0^{\infty}e^u(-s+1)du$

I don't think this is the way to do it..I need to use a limit from some variable, say $T$ that approaches infiity..

Comment: Where did $\frac{1}{1-s}$ come from? I would surmise some division, but where?

Comment: To continue with the problem, the result of the integrand would be $\frac{e^{-st + t + 7 + 1}}{1-s}$

Comment: Alright. I got $lim_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st+t+7}}{1-s}=0-\frac{e^7}{1-s}=-\frac{e^7}{1-s}$ But the answer is positive!

Comment: for $s>1$, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\int e^{t+7} e^{-s t} \, dt=\int e^{-s t+t+7} \, dt$

Let $-s t+t+7=u\to t-st=u-7\to t=\dfrac{u-7}{1-s}$

so we have $dt=\dfrac{du}{1-s}$ and the integral becomes

$\dfrac{1}{1-s}\int e^u \, du=\dfrac{e^u}{1-s}=\dfrac{e^{-s t+t+7}}{1-s}=F(t)$

Now perform the Laplace transform evaluating the integral function at $t=m\to\infty$ and at $t=0$. We get:
$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{t+7} e^{-s t} \, dt=\lim_{m\to +\infty } \, \frac{e^{-ms +m+7}}{1-s} - F(0)=0-\left(-\frac{e^7}{s-1}\right)=\dfrac{e^7}{s-1}$$
**Remark**

The term $e^7$ is a constant and could have been brought out of the integral from the beginning. I mean $\int e^{t+7} e^{-s t} \, dt=e^7\int e^{t} e^{-s t} \, dt$

For the sake of simplicity I left everything as you started it

hope this helps